Is my 3-phase induction motor generating backfeed?
enter image description hereA 480 V, 3 hp 3-phase motor to lift and lower a conveyor bed has a rectifier attached to the inner windings of the motor.  The rectifier, when energized creates 208 V DC to release the brake mounted to the non-working end of the motor.
When we lift the conveyor bed, the brake functions and stops the travel timely/immediately.
When we lower the conveyor bed and stop applying control voltage, the bed continues to lower, sometimes braking, sometimes lowering all the way to the ground too hard.
Is the induction motor capable of inducing enough voltage or power to keep the rectifier back-fed and subsequently applying release voltage to the brake? If I mechanically override the brake while the bed is raised, and release the override, the brake instantaneously stops the lowering of the conveyor bed, suggesting the opening of the motor control circuit isn't removing all of the voltage, or it's coming from another source like induction.

Welcome! Please draw a schematic or block diagram of how it’s connected. If you have any datasheet link for the motor in question, please update your question with it.

rectifier is connected to T7 and T8 in the motor weather head.  When the control voltage is dropped the motor is no longer powered by line voltage.  When the motor does not stop the T7 -T8 winding in the motor is presenting a spinning field generating a difference in potential verified by my meter.  Can this measured difference continue to supply the rectifier with enough potential to sustain its 205vdc output?  Attached is motor data plate and drawing of circuit to help clarify.

We resolved this circuit.  The rectifier jumper on terminal 3 and 4 can be used for control.  We ran a wire to either side of an aux contact on the motor starter and connected them to 3 and 4.  now we interrupt the residual backfeed/stray voltage from the still spinning motor at the same time we stop commanding the motor starter to close.  The brake now responds instantaneously traveling in both directions when it should.

(We resolved … rather than comment, answer your own question.)
